# Why always Jmockit mock interface return null, though i have specify result?

Tags: java, jmockit

jmockit version 1.46
java 1.8
simple code like below:

```
class PhoneControllerTest{

@Tested
PhoneController phoneController;

@Injectable
IPhoneService phoneService;
....
public void testMethod(@Tested Map map){
new Expections{{
  // example 1.mock success when param is 
  // primitive
  phoneService.call("12345");
  result="0";

  //example 2 .mock fail when param is 
  
   phoneService.call(map);
   result="0";

  
}}  
}}
interface IPhoneService{ 
     String call(String id);
     String call(Map map);
}
```

I am confused about example2,why it returns null instead 0？ how can i should do  that *result* works well in example2.  Is  @injectable has impact on "result" ?

Comment: The `Complex` object that you enter in the `Expectations` might be not equal to the one you enter later in the test. Can you show the full example code and the `Complex` class? Otherwhise it's just guessing what could be wrong.

Comment: i have updated code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hava slove the problem, just replace complex param with < T> any.
phoneService.call((Map)any);